# How to register onkeydown event for HTML5 canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I would like to write a snake game demo with HTML5 `<canvas>` element. I've tried to register the Keyboard(onkeydown) event, but it's not working.

Code:

```
   canvas.onkeydown = divertDirection; //don't work
   //canvas.addEventListener("keydown", divertDirection, false);  //don't work

   //根据键盘来调振蛇移动的方向
   function divertDirection(ev) {
        console.log(ev);
    }

    //register this event for widnow
   window.addEventListener("keydown", divertDirection, false); //ok
```

Comment: I'm Chinese, my English is not good! If there are any syntax errors, I'm very sorry. Thank you to help me to correct syntax errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As jing3142 has said, you can't listen for keyboard events on elements that are not designed for them.

However, you can force an element to be designed for them.

```
canvas.tabIndex = 1000;
```

Now you can use `canvas.addEventListener` with keyboard events.

This is preferable over `window.addEventListener` because then you don't interfere with any other elements on the page such as actual input elements.

Note that you may see a dotted outline in some browsers when the canvas has focus. To remove this:

```
canvas.style.outline = "none";
```

Have fun!

Comment: Does not seem to work on google chrome. Just tried to replicate this and event handlers don't run. After a bit more of testing - it starts to work once I click into the canvas (give it focus...). Other events, e.g. ``mousemove`` do not need that focus apparently.

Comment: You also need to give it focus with `canvas.focus()`. Clicking in it didn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

If an HTML element is not designed for text input then you cannot set a keydown event for it.

As you have done use

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", divertDirection, false);
```

then use the divertDirection function to change the direction of the snake object. If you have more than one snake then use different keys for each snake.

Comment: I see, thank you very much.

I try register keydown event for <div> element, but not work still.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onkeydown.asp. 
The website note: "the onkeydown attribute cannot be used with: <base>, <bdo>, <br>, <head>, <html>, <iframe>, <meta>, <param>, <script>, <style>, or <title>"

Comment: If you set attribute tabIndex for element(except not used), then register keydowm event, can work.
As follows:
  <canvas id="snake" width="400" height="600" tabindex=0>
  </canvas>
  canvas.addEventListener("keydown", divertDirection, false);