# Is Javascript's tabIndex property cross-browser?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, tabindex

I had a problem, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16492878/1223693) solved it. It uses the property `tabIndex`.

**Is this property cross-browser? Which browsers support it?**

Normally I would use Google for this, but oddly, nothing about this (except w3schools) appeared in [my search query](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+tabIndex+support), and w3schools is terrible and doesn't show which browser *versions* are supported, only which browsers. MDN doesn't say anything about it either.

Comment: What browsers/versions do you need to support? It's defined in [DOM Level 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.tabIndex#Specification) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534654.aspx) mentions IE5 and later.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Everything that supports `canvas` (since that's what I'm using anyway)

Comment: tabindex is supported fully since Internet Explorer 5.5 and in all other major browsers, like Firefox 1 and up, all versions of Chrome etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tabIndex` is so old, it has been standard since the earliest versions of browsers. In fact, it might even have been a part of the first ever HTML spec, although I can't say that for certain.

Basically, the reason you can't find compatibility tables is because ***everything supports it***.

Comment: Okay, just wanted to make sure. Thanks!