# Fabric.js iText : How to do text selection on iText while not allowing text modification?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have been reading docs and forums to solve this problem, but could not find an answer.

```
    var t1 = canvas.t1 =  _t1 = new fabric.IText(text1, {
      left: 100,
      top: 50,
    editable: true,
    selectable: false,
         width: 300,
     height: 150,
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    fontSize: 20,
      fill: '#f4b642',

} );

var t2 = canvas.t2 =  _t1 = new fabric.IText(text2, {
      left: 200,
      top: 150,
    editable: false,
    selectable: true,
    width: 300,
     height: 150,
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    fontSize: 20,
      fill: '#333',

} );

canvas.add(t1,t2);
t1.enterEditing();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qgeryu9o/2/

As shown on the fiddle by the upper iText element , I would like to 
access directly to the text at page load , this just to select 
    some words or sentences.

Using itext.enterEditing(), as on the upper itext box, this works fine except
 that it allows also what I do not want :  to delete, add, or modify the text.

In setting itext.editable to false ( as on fiddle lower iText element) 
    the text cannot be modified , but there is no way to show selection.

I tried to catch keydown events on the container div as suggested on this thread.
 [fabric.js canvas listen for keyboard events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684323/fabric-js-canvas-listen-for-keyboard-events)

But it does not work for me (tried on Chrome, Firefox), the event is not fired on itext in editing mode.

Thanks for your help.

Mike

Comment: You want to select text only?

Comment: Yes Durga, the idea is to associate some sound to words for instance ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not find a Fabric.js parameter allowing selection but no editing, I used a work-around.

At first I wanted to remove listeners set on the hidden textarea.
But, as bind() is used , there is no way to remove these listeners 
without modifying fabric.js :

```
fabric.util.addListener(this.hiddenTextarea, 'keydown', this.onKeyDown.bind(this));
fabric.util.addListener(this.hiddenTextarea, 'keyup', this.onKeyUp.bind(this));
```

So, I just have overwritten the  onInput() and onKeydown methods.

```
t1.onInput = function() {
    console.log("no input on t1") ;
    return false } ;

t1.onKeyDown = function() {
    console.log("no onKeyDown on t1") ;
    return false } ;
```

It works fine as shown on the corrected fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qgeryu9o/4/

If there is a more direct way to get the same result (selection but no edition), I would be happy to hear about it.

Thanks